# Node.js serve HTML, but can't load script files in served page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

i'm trying to make a little login page using a mongoDB database and Node.js + express. I'm new to Node.js so maybe the solution is easier than i thought.
The problem is: when i serve the HTML file when connecting to the server page, i can't use the JavaScript file referenced in the html file. How can i fix it?
P.s the index.html and client.js files are all located in a folder named "client".

Code:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(__dirname + 'client'));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));
});
```

HTML File:

```
 <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Login</title>
    <meta name="description" content="Login Page">
    <meta name="author" content="AlbertoCoder">
    <script src="/client/client.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You're able to use it, but you need to serve that javascript file from your server through a valid path.

In your HTML you're trying to retrieve the javascript file from `/client/client.js`

**The hint here is:**

Imagine the following URL of your server `http://myserver:8080/`

Now, your HTML is trying to retrieve the js file through `http://myserver:8080/client/client.js`

As you can see, your server is not serving that assets, thus you won't be able to retrieve that js file.

**Do the following:**

```
app.get('/client/client.js', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client.js'));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/client/index.html'));
});
```

Comment: if i did get it right, this should send the javascript file when i try to access the page /client/client.js in the server right? But if i want to send the html page with the script when the user access the main page ("/"), should i use the same function? Because it gives me an error about the headers can't be set after they're sent. P.s thanks, this was really heplful! :)

Comment: No, you mustn’t send at the same time.  Just put those gets separately and the browser will make two requests, one for index and another for client.js.

Comment: Oh i see! The app.get() method, execute the anonymous function when the client connect to any page or when it goes to that page?

Comment: Done, sorry for not doing it earlier, first time i use stackoverflow ahaha

Comment: @AlbertoCalabrese I am facing the same issue. If I apply your way you posted, browser displays the code inside .js file. 

You can check it here if you like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64636438/module-type-is-not-detectable-on-a-nodejs-with-vanillajs-configured-project

Answer (score 6):

Create a virtual path.

```
app.use('/client', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
```