# Js file not loading in node js server

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I have a node js server when I run HTML page in local host i get the **error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <** in the console because **my local js and css files** are not able to be loaded.
i have gone through - [Node.js serve HTML, but can't load script files in served page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48050666/node-js-serve-html-but-cant-load-script-files-in-served-page)
but it didn't worked

i have a file structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu9CQ.png)

my server code server.js

Node js:-

```
var express = require('express');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("Global");
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 7000;

http.createServer(app).listen(7000);
```

My HTML file index.html is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>sample spa app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>

    <div>
        <h2>you are in index.html</h2>
    </div>

   <div id="app">

   </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
    <script src="public/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>sample spa app</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <li><a href="#home">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>

    <div>
        <h2>you are in index.html</h2>
    </div>

    <div id="app">

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/app.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: in my case this works : " <script type="text/javascript" src="/script.js"></script> "

Answer (score 0):

> `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/html" href="css/style.css">`

The static handler will try and find a file `sampleProject/public/css/style.css`

> `<script src="public/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

The static handler will try and find a file `sampleProject/public/public/js/app.js` (yes, I wrote `public/public`).

None of these exist, therefore the static handler lets the request pass to the next route. The next route forces `sampleProject/public/index.html` to be served, whatever the request is. Hence your error.

#### Option A: isolate statically-served files

> `app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

(As a side note you should `require('path')` and declare `express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))`, which is safer and more portable than manually concatenating.)

This tells the application to use the static handler only if the route begins with `/public`.

#### Option B: always try to resolve files as static

Move your `css` folder to `public/css`, and change the path when calling your JS to:

> `<script src="/js/app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Read about the bases [here](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html).