# Module type is not detectable on a NodeJs with vanillaJs configured project

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I created for this project, a nodejs server configured to accept javascript as es6 modules. Server runs successfully, however when I am reaching the url: localhost:3333, am getting an error.

Please note that node is updated to the latest version.

I created the nodejs server:

```html
import http from 'http'
import express from 'express'
import path from 'path'
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const app = express();
const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url)
const __dirname = path.dirname(__filename)

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.static("express"));

app.use('/', function(req,res){
    console.log(__dirname);
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'));
})

const server = http.createServer(app);
const port = 3333;
server.listen(port);

console.debug('Listening on ', port);
```

I set the type, the main and the export inside the package.json:

```html
{
    "name": "node-ex-website",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    },
    "type": "module",
    "main": "./index.js",
    "exports": "./index.js"
}
```

I inserted the script in the html mentioning that is a type of a module:

```html
<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
```

However browser responds with an error:

```html
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

I don't understand why it throws an error since I configured everything to be as modules

error above is thrown for index.js which contains:

```html
import Navigation from "./src/navigation.js";

onload = () => {
  const navigationFields = ["Home", "CV"];
  new Navigation(navigationFields);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I created for this project, a nodejs server configured to accept javascript as es6 modules.

That doesn't matter.

Your error message is **client side**.

You have two different JS programs. One running through Node.js (which creates a web server) and one running in the browser.

The error message is from the latter.

---

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.

So let's trace this:

> ```
> <script type="module" src="index.js"></script>
> ```

The browser is asking for `http://localhost:3333/index.js` and getting an HTML document. That isn't a JS file, so it errors.

Likely you don't have an `index.js` file in the `express` folder where you told Express to look for static files.

Comment: @QuentinI don't think is the navigation.js that causes the issue, because I get the same error even if I remove the import and the new Navigation() statement inside index.js

Comment: @ChristosMichael — Then it is is `index.js` itself which doesn't exist at the specified url.

Comment: I think I should send it with some way throu the nodejs. same as I am doing with index.html

Comment: Yes, that's what I said, except the part where you do it "like index.html" - static files should be served with a properly configured static module. The approach you've taken for index.html is long-winded, bloated, and doesn't play nicely with caching.

Comment: i found what i did wrong thanks to what you mentioned. Thanks. i posted as an answer if you want to check it. i was just passing wrong directory on express.static

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

I should specify the root directory like this: `app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

Thanks @Quentin

Answer (score -1):

Best way to configure your NodeJS to accepting E6 Syntax is by using Babel and not the **type:module** thing(Personal believe).

**To get started install the following packages**

- `npm i @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env`
- If your using **yarn** then `yarn add @babel/core @babel/node @babel/preset-env`

**Now create a file called:** `.babelrc`

- In the .babelrc file do the following below

```
{
    "presets":["@babel/preset-env"]
}
```

**Finally time to setup your package.json scripts**

- `"start":"babel-node server.js"`
- `"dev":"nodemon --exec babel-node server.js"`

By doing this now your NodeJS will be using ES6 and you wont even face any problems